# automatically read csv file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a function in VB.net that has this code inside:

```
filename = TextBox5.Text
FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)
```

There is an `OpenFileDialog1`, and when a file is chosen it puts the file path/name in `TextBox5`

When i click a button, it reads in the CSV file selected using `OpenFileDialog1`

I then have another function that has this code inside:

```
TextBox5.Text = "C:\file.csv"
```

In this second function, the `OpenFileDialog1` is not used as the function puts the file path/name in `TextBox5`

Its working fine when i choose the file and upload it using a `OpenFileDialog1` but when it puts the filename in `TextBox5` automatically (the second function), its not reading in the data

Comment: When is the first part triggered? You could handle the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: the first part is triggered on a button click when a file is chosen from the OpenFileDialog but i have another button that automatically chooses a file (so the OpenFileDialog is not used)

Comment: Then put the code in a method and call that method from both button's click-event handlers.

Comment: Does the file "C:\file.csv" exists ? Do you (your application) have permission to open a file from the C: directory ?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a method and call that from wherever i need it:

```
Public Sub OpenFile(Dim file As String)
    ' insert your code here '
End Sub

Sub FistButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    OpenFile(TextBox5.Text)
End Sub

Sub SecondButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    TextBox5.Text = "C:\file.csv"
    OpenFile(TextBox5.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: i am using FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input) because then each column in the CSV i am using Input(1, callsourcetype)
            Input(1, customercli)

Comment: @user3843997: i don't understand the problem. You have two buttons. Now i've provided those two click-event handlers. In both i'm calling the same method. In the second method the `TextBox5.Text` is changed programmatically before the method is called. Does it work as expected? If not, what is wrong?

Comment: @user3843997: sorry, it's still not clear what's not working. Why don't you call the method that you've already created from both button-click event-handlers. The first button triggers the  `OpenFileDialog` to let the user specify the path and the second button enters it programmatically. My code still does that (simplified).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private watcher As System.IO.FileSystemWatcher = Nothing
Public Sub AvisCsvMonitorStart(ByVal avisSettings As String)
    watcher = Nothing
    watcher = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

    'CSV監視
    'watcher.Path = "C:\Users\core01\Desktop\Mango\WinBin"
    watcher.Path = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    watcher.Filter = "VitalData.csv"  'Monitor *.txt files, set to "" to monitor all
    watcher.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or System.IO.NotifyFilters.CreationTime
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = False

    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf watcher_Changed
    AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf watcher_Changed
    AddHandler watcher.Deleted, AddressOf watcher_Changed
    AddHandler watcher.Renamed, AddressOf watcher_Renamed

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

'変更がある場合はCSVを監視する
Private Sub watcher_Changed(ByVal source As System.Object, _
 ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
    Select Case e.ChangeType
        Case System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed
            'CSVからデータを取得
            Call ParseCSV(e.FullPath)
        Case System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created
            MessageBox.Show("Has been Created", e.Name, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
        Case System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted
            MessageBox.Show("Has been Deleted", e.Name, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub watcher_Renamed(ByVal source As System.Object, _
 ByVal e As System.IO.RenamedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Has been Renamed", e.Name, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
End Sub


'CSVからデータを取得
Private Sub ParseCSV(ByVal path As String)
    Dim mIndex As Integer
    Dim mDate As String
    Dim mTime As String

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
    TextFieldParser(path)

        MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}

        MyReader.ReadLine() ' skip header

        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                Dim fields = MyReader.ReadFields() 'contains all the items
                mIndex = fields(0)
                Dim dateTime = fields(3).Split(" ")
                mDate = dateTime(0)
                mTime = dateTime(1)

            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```